# Django: how to get extra context

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create extra context for my Django app. In this case, the variable something_extra should be available in my_template.

It's not working. There is no error, but something_extra is just nothing (nothing is displayed)

in context_processors.py:

```
def extra_context(request):  
    return  {"something_extra" :"hey"}
```

in views:

```
def my_view(request)
    return render_to_response("my_template.html", {},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                "my_app.context_processors.extra_context", )
```

in template:

```
look here: {{something_extra}}
```

Comment: Must it be in Template_Context_Processors, or can you just have the context updated before rendering?

Comment: Did you double check all the app's names, path, module's names and function's names match? Your code seems ok

Comment: Try putting print statements inside everything that should be called and ensure that all the proper functions are called? Agreeing with @PauloBu that everything seems to check out. Code works fine for me.

Comment: Well, now that you all say it should work, it does! Not sure what is different... :)